# Linq to SQL count grouped elements generating a timeout

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
FruitID | FruitType
  23    |    2
  215   |    2
  256   |    1
  643   |    3
```

I want to get the count by `FruitType` given a list of `FruitIDs` called `TheFruitIDs`. This is what I have:

```
var TheCounter = (from f in MyDC.Fruits    
                  where TheFruitIDs.Contains(f.FruitID) 
                  group f by 0 into TheFruits
                  select new MyCounterMode()
                  {
                     CountType1 = (int?) TheFruits.Where(f => f.FruitType == 1).Count() ?? 0,
                     CountType2 = (int?) TheFruits.Where(f => f.FruitType == 2).Count() ?? 0,
                     .... all the way to CountType6      
                  }).Single();
```

This code works but the problem is that sometimes I get a timeout error because the query runs for too long. How can I change this code to avoid the timeout problem?

Comment: Are you sure this translates to a single query? It seems the projection could possibly yield 6 new queries per each row. Is this the case?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but `Count()` returns an `int`, not `int?`, even when converted to SQL;  therefore the null coalescing operator is unnecessary (and probably won't even work).  This is because when casting to `int?` it'll never have a null value as value of 0 is not null.  I'm surprised this compiled without wrapping the cast in an extra set of parentheses, but that could be a copy-paste thing.

Comment: You are going to have to take a look at the generated SQL and run it in the query analyzer.

Comment: `group f by 0 into TheFruits` what is the point of that?

Comment: How many elements will `TheFruitIDs` typically contain?

Comment: @GertArnold: less than 2000 (I've already been burned with the 2000 items limit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to do you query is to group by `FruitType` and then count the rows:

```
var countsDictionary = MyDC
  .Fruits
  .Where(f => TheFruitIDs.Contains(f.FruitID))
  .GroupBy(
    f => f.FruitType,
    (fruitType, fruits) => new { FruitType = fruitType, Count = fruits.Count() }
  )
  .ToDictionary(c => c.FruitType, c => c.Count);
```

This will efficiently create the following dictionary (assuming no data was excluded by the `where` part):

```
FruitType | Count
----------+------
1         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 1
```

If you really want to collapse this into a single object having counts for specific fruit types you then have to create this object:

```
var TheCounter = new {
  CountType1 = countsDictionary.ContainsKey(1) ? countsDictionary[1] : 0,
  CountType2 = countsDictionary.ContainsKey(2) ? countsDictionary[2] : 0,
  CountType3 = countsDictionary.ContainsKey(3) ? countsDictionary[3] : 0
};
```

There is another thing in your query that might be causing performance problems potentially resulting in timeouts: The list of fruit ID's in the `where` part is included in the query and if that list is very big it may slow down your query. There is nothing you can do about it unless you create this list from a previous query to the database. In that case you should try to avoid pulling the list of fruit ID's to the client side. Instead you should combine the query that selects the ID's with this query that counts the types. This will ensure that the entire query is executed server side.

You seem to be concerned about the structural change of the code. As long as you are creating anonymous objects it is hard to write reusable code. You could consider to just use the dictionary with the counts or something similar. Another option is to create a dynamic object with the counts. Personally, I do not like this solution but you may find it useful.

To simplify the code a class to store counts is needed:

```
class TypeCount {

  public TypeCount(Int32 type, Int32 count) {
    Type = type;
    Count = count;
  }

  public Int32 Type { get; private set; }

  public Int32 Count { get; private set; }

}
```

A dynamic object that has properties `CountType0`, `CountType1`, `CountType2` etc. based on a sequence of tuples:

```
class CountsDictionary : DynamicObject {

  readonly IDictionary<Int32, Int32> counts;

  public CountsDictionary(IEnumerable<TypeCount> typeCounts) {
    if (typeCounts== null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("typeCounts");
    this.counts = typeCounts.ToDictionary(c => c.Type, c => c.Count);
  }

  public override Boolean TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out Object result) {
    Int32 value;
    if (binder.Name.StartsWith("CountType") && Int32.TryParse(binder.Name.Substring(9), NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value) && value >= 0) {
      result = this.counts.ContainsKey(value) ? this.counts[value] : 0;
      return true;
    }
    result = 0;
    return false;
  }

}
```

An extension method to create the dynamic object:

```
static class CountExtensions {

  public static dynamic ToCounts(this IEnumerable<TypeCount> typeCounts) {
    return new CountsDictionary(typeCounts);
  }

}
```

Putting it all together:

```
var counts = MyDC
  .Fruits
  .Where(f => TheFruitIDs.Contains(f.FruitID))
  .GroupBy(
    f => f.FruitType,
    (fruitType, fruits) => new TypeCount(fruitType, fruits.Count())
  )
  .ToCounts();
```

You can then retrieve properties `counts.CountType1`, `counts.CountType2` and `counts.CountType3`. Other `count.CountType#` properties will return 0. However, as `counts` is dynamic you will not get any intellisense.

Comment: I need the grouping and the counter object to be populated in the DB and not in memory.

Comment: @frenchie: The grouping and the count will all be performed on the server side. Performing `ToList` or in this case `ToDictionary` will then pull the rows containing the fruit type and the count to the client side. I decided to use `ToDictionary` to make the lookup of each count more efficient but with only a few rows you might as well use `ToList` and then perform a linear search in the list for each of the counts.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that MyCounterModel is not populated in the DB. How can I populate it like I have it in my problem query?

Comment: @frenchie: You have timeout problems because the query in your question is inefficient. My answer (as well as at least one other answer) has provided what I believe is the most efficient way to group and count the records and it should not suffer from timeouts. I do not understand your statement about _MyCounterModel is not populated in the DB_. Any C# object exists and thus is "populated" on the client from  tabular data returned from the database. Your query returns one row with six columns. My query returns six rows with two columns. In addition your query causes timeouts on the server.

Comment: Yes, I understand your query is more efficient but I'm wondering how to implement your query into my code so that the output is mapped against the object model I have in one operation? The query is just a pattern example I'm using for this question. In reality, I have several queries that use counters and these counters are actually subqueries of much bigger queries. I isolated the timeout problems to the counters in the subqueries and that's why I'm asking about how to populate the object models. But yes, your query is the direction I'll be going; I already tested it and performance is great!

Comment: @frenchie: With your current question I do not see how having two lines of code instead of one line to return the desired object is a problem. Perhaps you could expand a little on your question so it becomes easier to understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: Well as I have it, the query returns the counter object exactly as I use it throughout my code. I realize that the current query has performance issues and so it will change. The problem is that if I return a dictionary like you have it, then in my business logic I need to update the code so that the output of the query is further processed to map that dictionary to my object. I'm hoping to avoid that step by having the query returning the counter object model just like it's doing now.

Comment: @frenchie: You requirement seems to be purely aesthetic. You are doing a sort of pivot by taking the group counts which comes from the database as rows and pivoting these into an anonymous object with a property for each row. This is not really possible to do in a reusable way unless you use something that is not an anonymous object. I have edited my answer to provide one possible solution. However, personally, I would not do it like that. I would rather stick with a dictionary or dictionary like object and then query that for the counts when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into implementing it in my code as a subquery. And thanks for your effort too!

Answer (score 2):

This is what your query translates to:

```
SELECT
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C1],
[Limit1].[C2] AS [C2],
[Limit1].[C3] AS [C3],
[Limit1].[C4] AS [C4],
[Limit1].[C5] AS [C5],
[Limit1].[C6] AS [C6],
[Limit1].[C7] AS [C7]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (2)
    [Project13].[C1] AS [C1],
    CASE WHEN ([Project13].[C2] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project13].[C3] END AS [C2],
    CASE WHEN ([Project13].[C4] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project13].[C5] END AS [C3],
    CASE WHEN ([Project13].[C6] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project13].[C7] END AS [C4],
    CASE WHEN ([Project13].[C8] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project13].[C9] END AS [C5],
    CASE WHEN ([Project13].[C10] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project13].[C11] END AS [C6],
    CASE WHEN ([Project13].[C12] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project13].[C13] END AS [C7]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Project12].[C1] AS [C1],
        [Project12].[C2] AS [C2],
        [Project12].[C3] AS [C3],
        [Project12].[C4] AS [C4],
        [Project12].[C5] AS [C5],
        [Project12].[C6] AS [C6],
        [Project12].[C7] AS [C7],
        [Project12].[C8] AS [C8],
        [Project12].[C9] AS [C9],
        [Project12].[C10] AS [C10],
        [Project12].[C11] AS [C11],
        [Project12].[C12] AS [C12],
        (SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent13]
            WHERE ([Extent13].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) AND ([Project12].[C1] = 0) 
            AND (6 = [Extent13].[FruitType])) AS [C13]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Project11].[C1] AS [C1],
            [Project11].[C2] AS [C2],
            [Project11].[C3] AS [C3],
            [Project11].[C4] AS [C4],
            [Project11].[C5] AS [C5],
            [Project11].[C6] AS [C6],
            [Project11].[C7] AS [C7],
            [Project11].[C8] AS [C8],
            [Project11].[C9] AS [C9],
            [Project11].[C10] AS [C10],
            [Project11].[C11] AS [C11],
            (SELECT
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent12]
                WHERE ([Extent12].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) 
                AND ([Project11].[C1] = 0) 
                AND (6 = [Extent12].[FruitType])) AS [C12]
            FROM ( SELECT
                [Project10].[C1] AS [C1],
                [Project10].[C2] AS [C2],
                [Project10].[C3] AS [C3],
                [Project10].[C4] AS [C4],
                [Project10].[C5] AS [C5],
                [Project10].[C6] AS [C6],
                [Project10].[C7] AS [C7],
                [Project10].[C8] AS [C8],
                [Project10].[C9] AS [C9],
                [Project10].[C10] AS [C10],
                (SELECT
                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                    FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent11]
                    WHERE ([Extent11].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) 
                    AND([Project10].[C1] = 0) 
                    AND (5 = [Extent11].[FruitType])) AS [C11]
                FROM ( SELECT
                    [Project9].[C1] AS [C1],
                    [Project9].[C2] AS [C2],
                    [Project9].[C3] AS [C3],
                    [Project9].[C4] AS [C4],
                    [Project9].[C5] AS [C5],
                    [Project9].[C6] AS [C6],
                    [Project9].[C7] AS [C7],
                    [Project9].[C8] AS [C8],
                    [Project9].[C9] AS [C9],
                    (SELECT
                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                        FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent10]
                        WHERE ([Extent10].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643))
                        AND ([Project9].[C1] = 0) 
                        AND (5 = [Extent10].[FruitType])) AS [C10]
                    FROM ( SELECT
                        [Project8].[C1] AS [C1],
                        [Project8].[C2] AS [C2],
                        [Project8].[C3] AS [C3],
                        [Project8].[C4] AS [C4],
                        [Project8].[C5] AS [C5],
                        [Project8].[C6] AS [C6],
                        [Project8].[C7] AS [C7],
                        [Project8].[C8] AS [C8],
                        (SELECT
                            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                            FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent9]
                            WHERE ([Extent9].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) 
                            AND ([Project8].[C1] = 0) 
                            AND (4 = [Extent9].[FruitType])) AS [C9]
                        FROM ( SELECT
                            [Project7].[C1] AS [C1],
                            [Project7].[C2] AS [C2],
                            [Project7].[C3] AS [C3],
                            [Project7].[C4] AS [C4],
                            [Project7].[C5] AS [C5],
                            [Project7].[C6] AS [C6],
                            [Project7].[C7] AS [C7],
                            (SELECT
                                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent8]
                                WHERE ([Extent8].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) 
                                AND ([Project7].[C1] = 0) 
                                AND (4 = [Extent8].[FruitType])) AS [C8]
                            FROM ( SELECT
                                [Project6].[C1] AS [C1],
                                [Project6].[C2] AS [C2],
                                [Project6].[C3] AS [C3],
                                [Project6].[C4] AS [C4],
                                [Project6].[C5] AS [C5],
                                [Project6].[C6] AS [C6],
                                (SELECT
                                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                    FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent7]
                                    WHERE ([Extent7].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) 
                                    AND ([Project6].[C1] = 0) 
                                    AND (3 = [Extent7].[FruitType])) AS [C7]
                                FROM ( SELECT
                                    [Project5].[C1] AS [C1],
                                    [Project5].[C2] AS [C2],
                                    [Project5].[C3] AS [C3],
                                    [Project5].[C4] AS [C4],
                                    [Project5].[C5] AS [C5],
                                    (SELECT
                                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                        FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent6]
                                        WHERE ([Extent6].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) 
                                        AND ([Project5].[C1] = 0) 
                                        AND (3 = [Extent6].[FruitType])) AS [C6]
                                    FROM ( SELECT
                                        [Project4].[C1] AS [C1],
                                        [Project4].[C2] AS [C2],
                                        [Project4].[C3] AS [C3],
                                        [Project4].[C4] AS [C4],
                                        (SELECT
                                            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                            FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent5]
                                            WHERE ([Extent5].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) 
                                            AND ([Project4].[C1] = 0) 
                                            AND (2 = [Extent5].[FruitType])) AS [C5]
                                        FROM ( SELECT
                                            [Project3].[C1] AS [C1],
                                            [Project3].[C2] AS [C2],
                                            [Project3].[C3] AS [C3],
                                            (SELECT
                                                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                                FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent4]
                                                WHERE ([Extent4].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) 
                                                AND ([Project3].[C1] = 0) 
                                                AND (2 = [Extent4].[FruitType])) AS [C4]
                                            FROM ( SELECT
                                                [Project2].[C1] AS [C1],
                                                [Project2].[C2] AS [C2],
                                                (SELECT
                                                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                                    FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent3]
                                                    WHERE ([Extent3].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) 
                                                    AND ([Project2].[C1] = 0) 
                                                    AND (1 = [Extent3].[FruitType])) AS [C3]
                                                FROM ( SELECT
                                                    [Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1],
                                                    (SELECT
                                                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                                        FROM [dbo].[Fruits]AS [Extent2]
                                                        WHERE ([Extent2].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)) 
                                                        AND ([Distinct1].[C1] = 0) 
                                                        AND (1 = [Extent2].[FruitType])) AS [C2]
                                                    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                                        0 AS [C1]
                                                        FROM [dbo].[Fruits]AS [Extent1]
                                                        WHERE [Extent1].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)
                                                    )  AS [Distinct1]
                                                )  AS [Project2]
                                            )  AS [Project3]
                                        )  AS [Project4]
                                    )  AS [Project5]
                                )  AS [Project6]
                            )  AS [Project7]
                        )  AS [Project8]
                    )  AS [Project9]
                )  AS [Project10]
            )  AS [Project11]
        )  AS [Project12]
    )  AS [Project13]
)  AS [Limit1]
```

Note that for each grouping the IN is evaluated again, generating a very large workload for large lists of IDs.

You have to split the job in two steps.

```
List<int> theFruitIDs = new List<int> { 23, 215, 256, 643 };

var theCounter = (from f in MyDC.Fruits
                  where theFruitIDs.Contains(f.FruitID)
                  group f by f.FruitType into theFruits
                  select new { fruitType = theFruits.Key, fruitCount = theFruits.Count() })
                  .ToList();
```

This translate to a much faster SQL. Note the ToList() at the end that force the execution of a single query.

```
SELECT
[GroupBy1].[K1] AS [FruitType],
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT
    [Extent1].[FruitType] AS [K1],
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Fruits] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[FruitID] IN (23, 215, 256, 643)
    GROUP BY [Extent1].[FruitType]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Now you can take the generated list and pivot it in memory to obtain your MyCounterMode.

```
var thePivot = new MyCounterMode
                {
                    CountType1 = theCounter.Where(x => x.fruitType == 1).Select(x => x.fruitCount).SingleOrDefault(),
                    CountType2 = theCounter.Where(x => x.fruitType == 2).Select(x => x.fruitCount).SingleOrDefault(),
                    CountType3 = theCounter.Where(x => x.fruitType == 3).Select(x => x.fruitCount).SingleOrDefault(),
                };
```

Comment: No, I need the grouping and the counter object to be populated in the DB and not in memory

Comment: What I proposed and explained is all done on the db. The list "theCounter" is just a list of six elements and the second grouping "thePivot" is just to transpose those six rows into six columns.

Comment: The problem is that in some queries, I use the same pattern to fill the counter as a subquery of a much larger query so I need to write the counter query as one stand alone query.

Comment: I think that what you want to do is not possible in a single query without the use of unsupported keywords like "PIVOT". I think that hitting the database two times is a lot better (really a lot) than your original implementation. Other solutions can be implemented but not in linq.

Comment: What do you think of Jahirul's answer?

Comment: I already commented on that. I can expand a little: the query is wrong, it will raise an exception. The generated sql is almost identical to your original example, so it is not an improvement. BTW to see the sql generated by a linq statement: MyDC.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

Comment: Ok, so how can I map the result of theCounter into my object model. If we have the line select new { fruitType = theFruits.Key, fruitCount = theFruits.Count() }) then how can this be mapped? If that can be done then the whole thing will work.

Comment: I am not sure of what you need to do but the object "thePivot" is of type "MyCounteMode". You can already use this object in your other linq query. If you want more help please extend the description of your question including what you really need to do.

Comment: It seems that the SQL you show is generated by Entity Framework. This question is tagged [linq-to-sql] which generates somewhat different SQL. However, I do believe that your conclusions about the overal structure of the generated SQL are correct.

Answer (score 1):

your LINQ generate saperate sql for each count, so u need to use TheFruits to count your items

try this

```
var TheCounter = (from f in MyDC.Fruits    
                  where TheFruitIDs.Contains(f.FruitID) 
                  group new {f.FruitType} by f.FruitType into TheFruits
                  select new MyCounterMode()
                  {
                     CountType1 = TheFruits.Count(f => f.FruitType == 1),
                     CountType2 = TheFruits.Count(f => f.FruitType == 2),
                     .... all the way to CountType6      
                  }).Single();
```

Comment: This looks good because the grouping and counting is done in the DB instead of in memory.

Comment: This query will generate 6 rows and the Single operator will then throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `group by` in-memory. Combining a group by with multuple counts will generate lots of subqueries, which can perform quite badly.

```
var tempResult = (from f in MyDC.Fruits where TheFruitIDs.Contains(f.FruitID)).ToList();

var TheCounter = (from f in tempResult
                  group f by f.FruitType into TheFruits
                  select new MyCounterMode()
                  {
                     CountType1 = (int?) TheFruits.Count(f => f.FruitType == 1),
                     CountType2 = (int?) TheFruits.Count(f => f.FruitType == 2),
                     .... all the way to CountType6      
                  }).Single();
```

Comment: Although this is true fro LINQ-to-SQL in general, here the `group by 0` makes only 1 group and one query. Nevertheless, I also think that doing the grouping (pivoting) in memory is better, so the database can simply concentrate on producing data.

Comment: No, I need the grouping and the counter object to be populated in the DB and not in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that `select` is being executed for each iteration!!

So try something like:

```
'var TheCounter = (from f in MyDC.Fruits     
                  group f by f.FruitID into TheFruits
                  select new KeyValuePair<int, int>(TheFruits.Key,TheFruits.Count())).ToDictionary(r=>r.Key,r=>r.Value);'
```

This will give you a dictionary with: Key- FruitId, Value- Count

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I always implement this (I build a simple console program to demonstrate):

**Fruit.cs**

```
public class Fruit
{
    public Fruit(int fruitId, int fruitType)
    {
        FruitId = fruitId;
        FruitType = fruitType;
    }

    public int FruitId { get; set; }
    public int FruitType { get; set; }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Data
        var fruits = new List<Fruit>
        {
            new Fruit(23, 2),
            new Fruit(215, 2),
            new Fruit(256, 1),
            new Fruit(643, 3)
        };

        // Query
        var query = fruits
            .GroupBy(x => x.FruitType)
            .Select(x => new {Name = x.Key, Total = x.Count()});

        // Output
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + ": " + item.Total);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The one you need to focus in is `query`. After using `GroupBy`, you will have a list of groups. For each group, the `Key` is the criteria to group (here is the `FruitType`). Then, we call `Count()` to get the number of element in that group.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dynamic way to do it where you're not limited by CountType #'s:

```
int typesOfCounts = 6;

IEnumerable<Fruit> theCounter = fruitList.Where(x => theFruitIDs.Contains(x.FruitID));

Dictionary<string, int> myCounterMode = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (var i = 1; i < typesOfCounts + 1; i++)
{
    string counterType = "CountTypeX";
    counterType = counterType.Replace("X", i.ToString());

    myCounterMode.Add(counterType, theCounter.Count(x => x.FruitType == i));
}

return myCounterMode;
```